# BBpress error wp-init

Tags: bbpress

I installed bbpress with the latest wordpress version 3.8 and I receive an error:

```
Notice: bbp_setup_current_user was called incorrectly. The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init(). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 2.3.) in /public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3049
```

What does mean?

Thanks

Comment: See bbPress issue: http://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/2412 Further details: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24169

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I enabled the [WebsiteDefender WordPress Security plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/websitedefender-wordpress-security/)

Disabling/removing this plugin solved this issue for me.  That plugin calls methods like  `acxUtil::hideWpVersionBackend( )` without going through the WordPress `add_action()` which seems to be causing the issue.